# http://emptycharacter.com/ couldn't trim the empty character value

Tags: html, angular

http://emptycharacter.com/ if I copy empty character from this site and paste I couldn't trim the empty character value and it's allowing me to save the empty character in Angular

```
http://emptycharacter.com/ 


if (this.utilService.isUndefined(this.name) || (!this.utilService.isUndefined(this.name) &&
 this.utilService.isUndefined(name.trim()))) { console.log("ERROR") };
```

if it contains empty space I could able to catch it.

I hope you guys can help

Comment: Can you put some code of angular? Which type of data you want to allow to store?

Comment: I have updated my code

Comment: Space and empty character is totally different. So you dont want to allow space only or empty character too?